# Why is my text stacked with display flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The image below shows my problem. My text is being stacked because it is displayed flex. There will be a lot more fields just like this one so I do not want to put a set width for all of them.

[image: Image of text stacked instead of in line]

I have tried width: auto but that doesn't work.

I can just expand the width to around 15% but I will have a lot more fields just like this one so I do not want to put a set width for all of them.

```
<div class="container">
        <h2>Section I.</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col one">
                <label for="origin__location">Origin Location</label>
                <div class="underline"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    [.container{
    margin-left: 1em;
  }
  .row{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  .col{
    display: flex;
  }
  .one{
    flex: 1;
  }
  label{
    width: auto;
  }
  .underline{
    border-bottom: solid .5px #000;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 1em;
  }
```

I want my text to be in one line and work for words with more and/or fewer characters than what I already have.

Answer (score 2):

I added `white-space:pre;` to `label`.

```css
.container{
    margin-left: 1em;
  }
  .row{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  .col{
    display: flex;
  }
  .one{
    flex: 1;
  }
  label{
    width: auto;
    white-space:pre;
  }
  .underline{
    border-bottom: solid .5px #000;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 1em;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <h2>Section I.</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col one">
                <label for="origin__location">Origin Location</label>
                <div class="underline"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have never seen that before and it will definitely be useful to me later on.

Comment: You're welcome :) Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `width` definition for you `label`element, either a fixed width or a percentage:

```css
  .container{
    margin-left: 1em;
  }
  .row{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  .col{
    display: flex;
    width: 120px;
  }
  .one{
    flex: 1;
  }
  label{
    width: 25%;
  }
  .underline{
    border-bottom: 0.5px  solid black;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 1em;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <h2>Section I.</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col one">
                <label for="origin__location">Origin Location</label>
                <div class="underline"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```